# Export component list in Sitecore master db with PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am curious to know if it is possible to export Sitecore master db using PowerShell to a csv or to PowerBI?

I am exploring possibility to get information for a given UI component (e.g. “large hero”) which pages on the Sitecore platform across all tenants host this component?

E.g. Large Hero is hosted only on /membership page

Answer (score 5):

Since you already know the specific component that you want to find references for, you can use the [Get-ItemReferrer](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreferrer) commandlet.

For example:

```sh
$references = Get-ItemReferrer -Path master:\layout\Renderings\Feature\Teasers\MyComponent
$references | Show-ListView
```

This will return all reference to the component, including any `__Standard Values` of templates that you may have the rendering added to.

Internally [this uses the Links database](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/Cognifide.PowerShell/Commandlets/Data/GetItemReferrerCommand.cs#L55) so will be much faster than crawling the entire content tree.

Comment: What if I dont know the location of the item but I have the templateID?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to, you can pass an `Id` parameter, e.g. `Get-ItemReferrer -Id <String>`

Answer (score 3):

You could install [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com) and then use this PowerShell script to get list of renderings used on pages:

```
write-host 'Running script...'
Set-Location master:\content
$pages = get-item master:\content\home | get-childitem -Recurse
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$Results = @();
$DataPath = "C:\MySite\ComponentsInUse.csv"

foreach($page in $pages){

    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device -FinalLayout

    foreach($rendering in $renderings){

        if($rendering.ItemID -ne $null)
        {
            $renderingItem = Get-Item master: -ID $rendering.ItemID
            if($renderingItem -ne $null)
            {
                $Properties = @{
                    RenderingItemName = $renderingItem.Name
                    RenderingItemID = $renderingItem.ID
                    RenderingItemPath = $renderingItem.Paths.Path
                    UsedOnPage = $page.Name
                    UsedOnPageID = $page.ID
                    UsedOnPagePath = $page.Paths.Path
                }

                $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
            }
        }

    }
}

$Results | Select-Object RenderingItemName,RenderingItemID,RenderingItemPath,UsedOnPage,UsedOnPageID,UsedOnPagePath | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $DataPath

write-host 'Script ended'
```

Script was inspired from [this page](https://codebuildplay.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/sitecore-powershell-how-to-create-a-list-of-renderings-in-use/) so please take a look there for further references and examples. I have changed it to suit your needs.